# udev doesn't apply changes recursively

Tags: ubuntu, udev

I'm working with a [beaglebone black board](http://beagleboard.org/BLACK) ([ubuntu](http://beagleboard.org/latest-images) release for ARM architecture), which has some general purpose input/output ([GPIO](http://elinux.org/images/3/33/GPIO_Programming_on_the_Beaglebone.pdf)) interface to read sensors/drive motors etc.. which are configurable by 'exporting' the wanted pin using the following commmand:

```
bbb@arm:/sys/class/gpio$echo 30 > export
```

here the default folder and its contents:

```
bbb@arm:~$ ls -l /sys/class/gpio/
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bbb users 4096 Jan  6 12:13 export
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb users    0 Jan  6 12:13 gpiochip0 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/44e07000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb users    0 Jan  6 12:13 gpiochip32 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb users    0 Jan  6 12:13 gpiochip64 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb users    0 Jan  6 12:13 gpiochip96 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ae000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip96
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bbb users 4096 Jan  6 12:13 unexport
```

Since I want to use those pins as a normal user I tried to configure some rules to change the proprietary and user's group through the following rule:

```
bbb@arm:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-gpio.rules 
KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:users /sys/class/gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/class/gpio'"
KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:users /sys/class/virtual/gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/class/virtual/gpio'"
```

It works pretty good and the rule gets loaded while booting.
BUT if I export a pin, that I want to use:

```
bbb@arm:/sys/class/gpio$ echo 30 > export
bbb@arm:/sys/class/gpio$ cd gpio30
bbb@arm:/sys/class/gpio/gpio30$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  7 16:16 active_low
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan  7 16:16 device -> ../../../44e07000.gpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  7 16:16 direction
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  7 16:16 edge
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jan  7 16:16 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jan  7 16:16 subsystem -> ../../../../../../class/gpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  7 16:15 uevent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jan  7 16:16 value
```

I have the problem that all subdirectory and folders still have root as a ownwer and as a group. So I cannot configure the single pin (gpio) using my user account.

How should I modify my rules to get everything the new exported folder under my user's name (bbb) and group (users) ?????

Comment: That's a great question, I'm stuck right now with PWM that I am trying to export. The exported PWM channel is always owned by root!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I take back everything I said after testing on my Pi.  Add one additional rule to your current file:
`KERNEL=="gpio*",SUBSYSTEM=="gpio",ACTION=="add",PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:users /sys%p;chmod -R 770 /sys%p'"`

Now test with: `echo 30 > export`

If you do an `ls -l /sys/class/gpio30` it looks like it's still owned by root, but if you notice it is a link to /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio30.
`ls -la /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/gpio30`
and you'll see your script has run successfully.

This might help: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=9667

Comment: Yeah...it works!!!!