# udev creates the right rules, but rights disappear as soon as I try to access files via C++

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, directory, ls, udev

I'm facing a really strange problem using udev.
As I already explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253904/udev-doesnt-apply-changes-recursively) I'm trying to access some folders/files as **a no root user**
Here are my udev rules for the gpio folder:

```
KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R dave:users /sys/class/gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/class/gpio'"
KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R dave:users /sys/class/virtual/gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/class/virtual/gpio'"
KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R dave:users /sys%p; chmod -R 770 /sys%p'"
```

which apply in the right way as expected to do. Infact after a reboot I get the rights I defined in the rules:

```
dave@arm:~$ ls -l /sys/class/gpio/
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dave users 4096 Jan  9 20:56 export
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave users    0 Jan  9 20:56 gpiochip0 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/44e07000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave users    0 Jan  9 20:56 gpiochip32 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave users    0 Jan  9 20:56 gpiochip64 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave users    0 Jan  9 20:56 gpiochip96 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ae000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip96
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dave users 4096 Jan  9 20:56 unexport
```

Now: it happens something really strange. I wrote I simple C++ program which does use the boost libraries to access and to write into files.  Here I post a scracth of my program which consists of classes just as an example:

```
/*
 * @brief drives the gpio-pin high or low
 * @param the pin number, the state (high or low)
 * @return the success of the operation
 * 
 */
int GPIOclass::digitalWrite( unsigned int pin_label, unsigned int state ) 
{
    /* Check whether the Pin state has been correctly set or not */
    if( ( state != HIGH ) && ( state != LOW ) ) {
        std::cerr << "WARNING: Check again the value you want to write. It must be HIGH or LOW!" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Write the desired Pin value */
    boost::filesystem::fstream fs;

    boost::filesystem::path path_pin = "/sys/class/gpio";
    path_pin /= "/gpio" + std::to_string( pin_label );
    path_pin /= "/value";

    fs.open( path_pin, std::fstream::out );
    if( fs.is_open() ) {
        fs << state;
        fs.close();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: I couldn't open " << path_pin << " file" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The strange thing is that I cannot access the required pin, because in the exported folder I found only one link and not the usual files and folders to drive the gpio. What I find is the only entry:

```
dave@arm:~$ ls -l /sys/class/gpio/gpio60
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave users 0 Jan  9 20:58 /sys/class/gpio/gpio60 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio/gpio/gpio60
```

**But** going into the directory I can see more files and folders than above:

```
dave@arm:/sys/class/gpio/gpio60$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwx--- 1 dave users 4096 Jan  9 21:11 active_low
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave users    0 Jan  9 21:11 device -> ../../../4804c000.gpio
-rwxrwx--- 1 dave users 4096 Jan  9 21:11 direction
-rwxrwx--- 1 dave users 4096 Jan  9 21:11 edge
drwxrwx--- 2 dave users    0 Jan  9 21:11 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave users    0 Jan  9 21:11 subsystem -> ../../../../../../class/gpio
-rwxrwx--- 1 dave users 4096 Jan  9 21:11 uevent
-rwxrwx--- 1 dave users 4096 Jan  9 21:11 value
```

so it seems that there are some visibility rules or something like that. Why I get 2 different results if **I look into the folder from outside** or if **I look from inside the folder**?

Starting the same program using sudo works perfectly.

---

**UPDATE:** I did exactly what suggested in the answer below. The answer is right but I can't use the exported gpio as a normal user.
So I m looking for a new rule which let me to change the group and the owner of the linked folder:

```
/sys/devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio
```

as suggested in the answer.

The problem is now that I m trying to write a new rule which does exactly that. Once I retrieved the following informations:

```
@arm:~/workspace/auto/build$ udevadm info --path=/sys/devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio --attribute-walk

Udevadm i...

  looking at device '/devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio':
    KERNEL=="4804c000.gpio"
    SUBSYSTEM=="platform"
    DRIVER=="omap_gpio"
    ATTR{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/ocp':
    KERNELS=="ocp"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
    KERNELS=="platform"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

I added the following rules to my existing udev-rule:

```
KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:gpio /sys/class/gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/class/gpio'"
KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:gpio /sys/class/virtual/gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/class/virtual/gpio'"
KERNEL=="gpio*", SUBSYSTEM=="gpio", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:gpio /sys%p; chmod -R 776 /sys%p'"
KERNEL=="4804c000.gpio", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:gpio /sys/devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio'"
KERNEL=="481ae000.gpio", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:gpio /sys/devices/platform/ocp/481ae000.gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/devices/platform/ocp/481ae000.gpio'"
KERNEL=="481ac000.gpio", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:gpio /sys/devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio'"
KERNEL=="44e07000.gpio", SUBSYSTEM=="platform", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R bbb:gpio /sys/devices/platform/ocp/44e07000.gpio; chmod -R 777 /sys/devices/platform/ocp/44e07000.gpio'"
```

Running as a normal user I still get the following error:

```
ERROR: I couldn't open "/sys/class/gpio/gpio67/value" file
ERROR: I couldn't open "/sys/class/gpio/gpio69/value" file
ERROR: I couldn't open "/sys/class/gpio/gpio66/value" file
ERROR: I couldn't open "/sys/class/gpio/gpio69/value" file
```

from my C++ program above.

I really can't understand since the rights are correctly set:

```
bbb@arm:~/workspace/build$ ls -l /sys/class/gpio/gpio60/
total 0
-rwxrwxrw- 1 bbb gpio 4096 Jan 11 17:50 active_low
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 device -> ../../../4804c000.gpio
-rwxrwxrw- 1 bbb gpio 4096 Jan 11 17:50 direction
-rwxrwxrw- 1 bbb gpio 4096 Jan 11 17:50 edge
drwxrwxrw- 2 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 subsystem -> ../../../../../../class/gpio
-rwxrwxrw- 1 bbb gpio 4096 Jan 11 17:50 uevent
-rwxrwxrw- 1 bb gpio 4096 Jan 11 17:50 value
```

and the problem with the link seems to be fixed now:

```
bbb@arm:~/workspace/build$ ls -l /sys/class/gpio
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio 4096 Jan 11 17:50 export
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 gpio48 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio/gpio/gpio48
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 gpio60 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio/gpio/gpio60
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 gpio66 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio/gpio/gpio66
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 gpio67 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio/gpio/gpio67
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 gpio68 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio/gpio/gpio68
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:50 gpio69 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio/gpio/gpio69
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:49 gpiochip0 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/44e07000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:49 gpiochip32 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:49 gpiochip64 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ac000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio    0 Jan 11 17:49 gpiochip96 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/481ae000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip96
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bbb gpio 4096 Jan 11 17:49 unexport
```

what I m doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:** I'm really having hard time to try to understand what is going in this distribution. I came up whit this [minimal example](http://pastebin.com/Rw8jnD7P) (under this [link](http://pastebin.com/vzgHRftQ) you can find the cmakelists to compile it) to open and write into the exported folders for each pin.
I'm now using a beaglebone (with ubuntu). The uder rules are defined above. I didn't change them.

Trying to run the program with my user "bbb" I get the following errors:

```
bbb@arm:~/workspace/auto/test/build$ ./myprog 
ERROR: the direction of pin "/sys/class/gpio/gpio67/direction" cannot be set.
Reason: Permission denied
ERROR: the value of the "/sys/class/gpio/gpio67/value" cannot be defined.
Reason: Permission denied
...
```

I added the user "bbb" to all the groups which belongs to the default user "ubuntu".

What can I do?

Comment: What is the errno value after trying to open the file? What makes you think that it's a permission problem? Post a small, compilable program that reproduces the problem and that prints out the full error information.

Comment: Because running the same program with 'sudo' I can drive my GPIO pins exactly as expected. Tomorrow I m going to tell you what is the errno. I don't have the board right now.

Comment: The output of cerror is posted above.

Answer (score 2):

`/sys/class/gpio/gpio60` is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). That's a special type of file that points to another file. When accessing the file contents, symbolic links are transparent: they act like their target (the file they point to). But when listing directories, symbolic links appear as themselves; `ls -l` shows them with `l` in the leftmost column, and shows their target after `->` on the right. When accessing metadata, it depends.

`chmod -R … /sys/class/gpio` affects the directory tree starting at `/sys/class/gpio`. This includes entries such as `/sys/class/gpio/gpio60`. But `/sys/class/gpio/gpio60` is a symbolic link, pointing somewhere else in the directory tree; the `chmod` command does not affect the target of the symbolic link.

When you try to access files under `/sys/class/gpio/gpio60`, or when you run `cd /sys/class/gpio/gpio60`, this accesses the directory that the symbolic link points to (access to the content of the directory). This works as root but not as non-root because that directory is accessible to root only.

To make that directory accessible to other users, you would need to run `chmod … /sys/devices/platform/ocp/4804c000.gpio/gpio/gpio60`.

However, rather than change the ownership, it would be simpler to add your user to the `gpio` group:

```
adduser dave gpio
```

Comment: That's a very detailed explanation of the problem but it still doesn't fix my problem